# Why is only the product, and not its associated movements, being deleted?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to delete a product from the Product table while also deleting all the movements of that product from the product movements table(called Movement), but only the product is being deleted, and not its movements. Does anyone know why? This is the code:

```py
@app.route('/products/<int:product_id>/delete', methods=['GET', 'POST'])   
def delete_product(product_id):
    product = Product.query.get_or_404(product_id)
    movements = Movement.query.filter_by(product_id=product_id).all()
    for movement in movements:
        db.session.delete(movement)
    db.session.delete(product)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('The product has been deleted!', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('products'))
```

This is the model for the product table:

```py
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    product_movements = db.relationship('Movement', backref='item', lazy=True)
```

and this is the one for the movement table:

```py
class Movement(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    product = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    from_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    from_location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    to_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    to_location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Comment: This works for me using sqlite and sqlalchemy.  Perhaps `Movement.product_id` is not getting set correctly?  You could try setting `nullable=False` on `Movement.product_id`, which would prevent creating movements without product, or deleting products without deleting their movements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, I hadn't set set the values for product_id in the Movement table.

```
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        product = Product.query.filter_by(id=form.product.data).first()
        from_location = Location.query.filter_by(id=form.from_location.data).first()
        to_location = Location.query.filter_by(id=form.to_location.data).first()
        m = Movement(product_id = product.id, product = product.name, from_location_id = from_location.id, from_location = from_location.name, to_location_id = to_location.id, to_location = to_location.name, quantity = form.quantity.data)
        db.session.add(m)
        db.session.commit()
        movements = Movement.query.all()
        products = Product.query.all()
        locations = Location.query.all()
        return render_template('movements.html', movements=movements, products=products, locations=locations, form=form)
```

It works now.